# Google Drive Script - Change ownership of folders OAuth error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm working on a script to change the ownership of folders. But I'm stuck with a "oAuth error". Am I missing something in my code?

```
function getFolders(){
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
 var folders = DocsList.getAllFolders();
  for (var i in folders) {
  var oldOwnerEmail = (folders[i].getOwner());
   if (oldOwnerEmail != me) { 
   changeFolderOwner(me, folders[i], oldOwnerEmail);
  }
 }
}

function changeFolderOwner(newOwnerEmail, folder, oldOwnerEmail){
 var base = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
 var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('docs', base);
 fetchArgs.method = 'POST';
 var rawXml = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>"
 +"<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' "
 +"term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>"
 +"<gAcl:role value='owner'/>"
 +"<gAcl:scope type='user' value='"+newOwnerEmail+"'/>"
 +"</entry>";
 fetchArgs.payload = rawXml;
 fetchArgs.contentType = 'application/atom+xml';

 Logger.log(folder.getName());
 Logger.log(oldOwnerEmail);
 Logger.log(folder.getId());

 var url = base + encodeURIComponent(oldOwnerEmail) + '/private/full/'+folder.getId()+'/acl?v=3&alt=json';
 var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText(); 
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
 var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
 oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
 oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
 oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
 return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

After pressing authorize I get a error saying "OAuth error" when i run the debug. On this line:

```
var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google Apps Script, it is generally unnecessary to use OAuth unless you are attempting to connect to an external service, which isn't the case here.

What you want in this case is to use the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) service (instead of DocsList), which has [a Folder class with a setOwner() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#setOwner%28String%29).

Something like this will change the ownership of all the available folders:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  folder.setOwner(newOwnerEmailAddress);
}
```